# Rocker switch in bedroom stuck? possible obstruction?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light

Searched the site but didn't find anything similar to my question.
I have a rocker switch for my bedroom light. Actually, there are 3 switches all side by side with one 3-opening faceplate for all 3. This morning, the middle switch just stuck - like something was blocking it. I couldn't push the bottom half at all, it was just stuck in the on position. The switch itself didn't budge at all.

Not being the fix-it-myself guy AT ALL, I was hesitant to just go and buy a new switch. I turned the power off and took off the face plate. I unscrewed the top and bottom screw a bit on the rocker switch, pulling the switch out but not disconnecting any of the wiring, and all of a sudden the rocker moved again, almost like an obstruction had freed itself, maybe a tiny piece of drywall or something? Turned power back on and everything seems fine.

Should I still have it replaced? Is it a possible there is a safety mechanism in the switch that blocked the switch from moving, and I somehow un-did the safety, allowing it to turn on/off again?Or is it more likely (and safer) that I just dislodged something that was blocking the rocker mechanism, and now that it's free, everything is fine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There could have been something trapped behind the faceplate. At this point I would probably say that was the cause , However if it happens again something inside the switch is failing not really a safety issue because the plastic encases the contact set.
So go ahead and use it as long as it is switching it should be fine. If it hangs up again get a new switch turn the breaker off and swap wire(s) 1 at a time re mount and turn the power back on.

Comment: ...And take pictures just in case...+1